# Problem with UITabBar + NavController in secondView viewDidLoad isn't called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My Application is a Tabbar with a navController in each of it's tabs. Now, the problem is to add a custom info button to the navController in the SecondView. I've created the App in InterfaceBuilder and entered the name of the nib to Load there. If I run my App now, the SecondView is shown, but the problem is, that the viewDidLoad is not called.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?9d8ed67dcc.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your viewDidLoad is not being called, that might mean that you haven't set the correct class identity for your UIViewController subclass in the nib file, and the nib is just loading a generic UIViewController.